# map view not moving on scroll

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

Im working on react native map and after adding View on the map, the map is not moving on scroll.
Normally when I scroll down or up, I get to see different parts of the map. However, when `View` is added, the map gets fixated at one location and I am not able to see different parts of the map.

```
 <MapView
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      initialRegion={this.state.region}
      showsUserLocation = {true}
      ref="map"
      >
      <View
        style={{flex: 3,  alignSelf: 'stretch',
    textAlign: 'center'}}
    >
     <Button title="click here"/>
    </View>

      </MapView>
```

The reson why I need the `view` is to add other components like buttons input fields and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps#overlaying-other-components-on-the-map) say that you need to absolute position the component you want to add other views over the map

> Absolutely position these elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
render() {
return (
<MapView
region={this.state.region}
/>
<OverlayComponent
style={{position: “absolute”, bottom: 50}}
/>
);
}
```